# ER = EPR and Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-gravity

Following the Maldacena-Susskind "ER = EPR" correspondence, what gravitational fact would the Heisenberg uncertainty principle correspond to?